# Regex: match text after specific symbol combination until the end of the word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have something like that

```
test/pull/1
test/pull/2
```

My goal is to grab

```
1
2
```

Closest I got is this, any help appreciated:

```
(?<=pull\/\s)(\w+)
```

Comment: You can make the `\s` optional `(?<=pull\/\s?)\w+` See https://regex101.com/r/n9RJ3S/1 or use a  capture group `\bpull\/\s?(\w+)`

Comment: Why are you using `\s` in lookbehind regex when your desired matches are right next to `pull/` ?

Comment: would this simple regex help ?
`test/pull/([0-9]{1,})`

Comment: the idea is to loop every line and get that number with the regex..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test/pull/([0-9]{1,})
```

if `test/pull/` is your unique identifier

```
pull/([0-9{1,}])
```

if your `pull` is your unique identifier

```
test/pull/([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,})
```

if your try to capture alphanumeric more than 1

```
([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,})$
```

if you don't know what your unique identifier is but you know it's always in the end of the word, and the text is alphanumeric

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this one:

```
([^\/]+$)
```

or if you are expecting non-digit characters:

```
(?<=pull\/).*$
```

And as mentioned in the comments, the .* will match till the end of the string, which might be too much. Even better:

```
(?<=pull\/)\w+
```

Comment: Note that the first pattern does not take `pull/` into account, and the second pattern is a negated character class which will exclude matching the chars `p` `u` `l`

Comment: The fourth bird: I have just tested the 2nd one here: https://regex101.com and it works. 
What do you mean by "pattern is a negated character class"?

Comment: Yes it works because 1 and 2 are not in the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Try matching `test/pull/apple1` https://regex101.com/r/CaBxSj/1

Comment: oh! I see... I thought only digits were expected there..
I'll try to edit this one.

Comment: It is not my downvote, I initially left a comment for you to improve  your answer pointing out the current matches. I would edit your answer, and remove the first 2 patterns. Then as the pattern you can suggest either `(?<=pull\/).*$` (but note that the `.*` will match till the end of the string, which might be too much) or you can suggest `(?<=pull\/)\w+` staying within the range of characters that the OP initially intended to match.

Comment: The fourth bird: I really appreciate that!